# Document frequency count and calculating TFIDF

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and have a task giving me lots of troubles. I have small file (3 lines) which i read using

```
lines = sc.textFile("Dome/test.txt")
```

The next line splits the text into elements of an array:

```
terms = lines.map(lambda line: line.split(" "))
```

Then I calculates the frequency of words in each document ('the': 4, 'by': 1, 'information': 1, 'based': 1,) and I am happy with this. Using the line below

```
frequency = terms.map(lambda term: Counter(term))
```

What I need now is how to calculate the document frequency? I expect to have an output like '--the: 30, based: 40 etc. and then calculate the TFIDF.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is TFIDF and document frequency? What output are you looking for?

Comment: Document Frequency: i am looking for the number of documents a specific word appears in. output like "word: 20", "word2: 30" e.t.c

Comment: what is a document then? please state your question in an understandable way.

Comment: @gen also the TFIDF means term frequency - inverse document frequency

Comment: @gen here is a sample of my document: from the below output, the word "Counter" signifies the beginning of a new document and have just cropped two document for better understanding

Comment: [Counter({'': 1, 'which': 1, 'Snitches': 1, 'determines': 1, 'Cassandra': 1, 'racks': 1, 'about': 1, 'the': 1, 'inform': 1, 'so': 1, 'and': 1, 'to.': 1, 'topology': 1, 'snitch': 1, 'data': 1, 'centers': 1, 'belong': 1, 'network': 1, 'A': 1, 'nodes': 1}), Counter({'and': 2, 'requests': 1, 'by': 1, '': 1, 'allows': 1, 'that': 1, 'to': 1, 'grouping': 1, 'machines': 1, 'replicas': 1, 'efficiently': 1, 'routed': 1, 'data': 1, 'centers': 1, 'distribute': 1, 'Cassandra': 1, 'are': 1, 'into': 1}),

Comment: Have a look at Lucene or Elasticsearch (Lucene with a REST API), have a look at python implementations of tf-idf extraction as simple as this one https://github.com/hrs/python-tf-idf or just pick up what you need from this Java example of implementing tf/idf w/out Lucene http://sujitpal.blogspot.ro/2008/09/ir-math-with-java-tf-idf-and-lsi.html

Comment: @Filip thanks for your comment. i have looked at the links and they would be helpful for the tf-idf calculation. However, i need to cross the document frequency step before i can move on to the last step(tf-idf). do you know how i can count the number of times a word appears in several documents? many thanks